# Tooltip behavior that treats a JComponent with subcomponents as a whole? (sans flicker)

Tags: java, swing, tooltip

I have a JComponent with several subcomponents, and I'd like it to have a tooltip that treats the component as a whole.

For instance, if you look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/284101/411282) to a similar question, the tooltip refreshes when you cross from one subcomponent to another, flickering briefly and changing position.  Compare this to a JLabel with an icon and text, where the tooltip stays in one spot throughout all the parts of the label.  In my application, the pieces are closely packed together, so the flicker from setting the tooltip independently for all the parts is quite distracting.

Is there a way to get the tooltipping to treat the JComponent as a whole?

Comment: Incidentally, can anyone explain an odd behavior? Two of the subcomponents are JLabels, an image and a text label.  The image does not block the container for the tooltipping---I don't need to setToolTipText on *that* JLabel---but the text JLabel does block it.  An ideal solution to the main question would be to prevent the text label from blocking the container, but I thought the difference between the two JLabels was puzzling enough to mention.

Comment: you can edit your question to add information :-)

Comment: don't quite understand the difference between the two labels - the "text label" does have a tooltip set? Or another mouse/Motion/-Listener?

Comment: anyway, your requirement is not supported. Worse: whatever you might try, most probably will clash somewhere - tooltipManager is designed to act strictly per-component

Comment: One is created like this: new JLabel(<an ImageIcon>) the other is new JLabel(<a String>); both are added with add().  If I setToolTipText on the *whole* container, then the image label inherits the tooltip, but the text label has no tooltip unless I separately call setToolTipText on it.

Comment: can't reproduce the difference (jdk6u27, vista)

Comment: sorry, (and thanks!) do you mean the icon doesn't show the tooltip without setToolTip on it, or do you mean the text label showed the tooltip when you only specified it on the containing JComponent?  (I'm on a mac, jdk6)

Comment: the second - parent tooltip is shown on both labels, as it should: the reason is that they are "mouseEvent-transparent" as long as they have no listener registered